# Convert String array to List of Objects by assigning the string(from array) as one of the parameter of the Object leaving other parameters as null

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, object

I have a String array

```java
adrs[] = {
    "BD Jules Ferry",
    "Rue de Republique",
    "Avenue de Julin"};
```

I have an Object named 'Address'  (//getter setter omitted just for simplicity)

```java
public class Address{

     adrsLine1 String;

     adrsLine2 String;

     adrsLine3 String;

     postalCode String;

}
```

I want to convert this `adrs[]` to `List<<Address>> addrsList`, by assigning each string in the array as `adrsLine1` parameter of `Address`.

Once converted each address object in my `addrsList` will be like,

- `addrsList.get(0)` will have [BD Jules Ferry, null, null, null]
- `addrsList.get(1)` will have [Rue de Republique, null, null, null]
- `addrsList.get(2)` will have [Avenue de Julin, null, null, null]

I use Java 8, Currently, I use `for loop` to achieve this, is there any short cut or more efficient way available in Java 8?

**Sample code:**

```java
private String[] AdrsArray = {"BD Jules Ferry", "Rue de Republique", "Avenue de Julin"};

List<Address> addrsList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String adrsLine : AdrsArray){
    Address address = new ReturnAddress();
    address.setAdrsLine1(adrsLine);
    addrsList.add(address);
}
```

**Output:**

```java
Address address = addrsList.get(0); 
address.getAdrsLine1() //should have "BD Jules Ferry"
address.getAdrsLine2() //should have null
address.getAdrsLine3() //should have null
address.getAdrsPostalCode() //should have null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `streams` available in Java 8 to simplify your code as shown below.

```
List<Address> addrsList = Arrays.stream(adrs).map(adr -> {
    Address address = new ReturnAddress();
    address.setAdrsLine1(adr);
    return address;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Address> addressList = Arrays.stream(AdrsArray)
                                  .map(Address::new)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You have to add a constructor to Address class that accepts `adrsLine1`.

```
public class Address{

     private String adrsLine1;

     private String adrsLine2;

     private String adrsLine3;

     private String postalCode;

     Address(String address1) {
       adrsLine1 = address1;
     }

}
```

Comment: I dont want to modify the Address class as i use jhipster to generate the domain class every time when there is a change needed, so it will override this custom constructor. I have accepted Suraj answer which seems to be more adapt to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams. I would recommend you to implement a constructor in class `Address`, such as

```
Address(String adrsLine1) {
  this.adrsLine1 = adrsLine1;
}
```

Then you can do it with this short code snippet:

```
List<Address> addrsList = Arrays.stream(adrs)
    .map(adr -> new Address(adr))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

If you need a specific List type such as `ArrayList`, you should use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, otherwise (if you can accept any list type) you can use just `Collectors.toList()` instead.

Comment: In the case of adding a constructor that takes in the address, this could be simplified to: `Arrays.stream(adrs).map(Address::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Jordan, yes, I know. But I did not see if it will make sense to have this constructor. When you have another constructor like one of signature ```Address(String, String, String, String)```, it is a little bit simpler to adapt for someone new to lambdas.